# iOS: Upload encounters "Invalid URL server" with DATA_URL DestinationType in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic4

I've been working on a project that uploads text data with captured image to a server. But then I'm encountering this error in iOS but it works well with Android. I already tried using `NATIVE_URI` and `FILE_URI` but no good.

Here is the error it produces in Xcode terminal:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
const options: FileUploadOptions = {
                  fileKey: 'webcam',
                  fileName: 'dtr.jpg',
                  chunkedMode: false,
                  headers: {}
                };

const cameraOptions: CameraOptions = {
                  quality: 50,
                  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                  allowEdit: false
                };

this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions).then((imageData) => {
    this.yourImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;

    const endPoint = ENPOINT_URL;
    fileTransfer.upload(this.yourImage, endPoint, options)
        .then(
            (data) => {
                this.dismiss();
                $('.on-success').show();
            },
            (err) => {
                this.presentAlertConfirm(JSON.stringify(err));
            });
        }, (err) => {
            this.dismiss();
            this.presentAlertConfirm(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
...
```

**Version information**

- MacOS Mojave 10.14.6
- Xcode 11
- Ionic CLI 5.4.2
- Cordova 9.0.0
- Node 6.9.0

**Testing information**

- iPhone X
- iOS 13

Comment: DATA_URL is gives you base64 and FILE_URI gives you file path, so if you are using base64 string you don't need file upload plugin. You can do it directly with post request of http

Comment: @PareshGami I already tried the FILE_URI but it still gives the same error. But in Android it's working fine with DATA_URL in file upload plugin.

Comment: For iOS, what you will get in error block of fileTransfer?

Comment: It returns `ERROR_CODE = 2` that means `INVALID_URL_ERR` but it's working fine in Android.

Comment: Sure I can help you. Please try to contact me at gamiparesh5@gmail.com

Comment: email sent @PareshGami thank you very much!!

Comment: Also if you are uploading by http post request, you probably will not need the 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' part in front of the base64 string. I doubt your server side will expect that

Comment: @DimitriosMatanis have you tried uploading using cordova's fileupload plugin?

Comment: That plugin is deprecated as it's not required anymore. You can read about it on their GitHub page